Why is Ubuntu randomly suspending itself by default?
This is extremely annoying behavior and it seems to be new.
After installing Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop on a computer with NVIDIA GPU RTX4090, the system at some point decides to suspend itself, without any intervention by the user, without me configuring this anywhere.
I found this website for how to disable suspending/sleeping etc but it seems too harsh: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2515869
Is there not some simple configuration option where I can tell Ubuntu to please not do what I never told it todo and instead only suspend/shut down etc when I tell it to do so like it was in all the decades before?
Why is this happening on every machine I newly install with Ubuntu 24.04?

On Ubuntu Desktop, look at Settings --> Power
